# Two jobs on my CV with the same role

Tags: resume

When writing my CV, I noticed my last role (and the other before that) were pretty much like-for-like just at different companies (they weren't taken over, I just left for a better salary)

Should I put it like this

```
**(Job role)**

*Employer 1 (date-date)*

*Employer 2 (date-date)*

(Job description)
```

or just as two separate jobs, worded differently even though it was a pretty much identical job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This format is more standard in my experience, even if the titles and job requirements are the same. In reverse chronological order:

Employer 1 (date-date)

(Job Title)

(Job Description)

Employer 2 (date-date)

(Job Title)

(Job Description)

Comment: thank you. that's how it is at the moment, but I was just looking to save a bit of room since I'm applying for jobs of a different role than I had before so it doesn't really seem that relevant.